# Email forwarding while having another Host

Tags: email, dns, cross-domain, email-forwarding

I have this domain www.example.com and in its DNS there are 4 records

1st: 2 Nameserver records

2nd: CName(Alias) Record which is pointing host as www to some address

3rd: A(Host) Record where @ is host and pointing to an IP address

Im also forwarding my naked domain example.com to www.example.com with 301(permanant) type forwarding.

I bought the domain from Godaddy, which provides free email forwarding service with domain.

Now when im creating a email xyz@example.com which is forwarding all the emails to abc@gmail.com from godaddy domain control panel, then after doing this when im sending testing email to xyz@example.com from hello@gmail.com then I should receieve my testing email on abc@gmail.com but im not getting it.

Is there anything wrong with anything? Do the DNS records need to be modified?
I searched over the internet and what i found was that i cant use 2 different services(hosting+email) from 2 different sources..is it correct?
Please Help

Comment: The server that handles mail to example.com is determined by the MX records for example.com.  Do you have any MX records setup for example.com?  If you're not sure, open a command prompt, and type `nslookup -q=MX example.com`.

Comment: NO There are no records for the domain, i checked it in the DNS records of my domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MX DNS records need to be pointed to godaddy's secureserver.net servers for the forwarding to work properly.

https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5444/checking-your-mx-record-settings-in-the-email-control-center

Comment: There was option to autocorrect the MX records. Autocorrection added 2 records to the MX record in DNS 1 with priority 0 pointing to mailstore1.sercureserver.net with host as @ and other with priority 10 pointing to smtp.sercureserver.net with host as @ but still not working, do i need to wait?

Comment: MS or MX? MX is the ones you want. Also depending on the TTL settings, the changeover might take up to a day.

Comment: Sorry for the typing mistake, corrected the previous comment please check it

Comment: what should be the TTL Value? by default its 1Hour, SHould i Change to lesser value?

Comment: 1hr is fine if you don't expect to keep switching your email config

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66785/discussion-between-maitiest-and-srdjan-grubor).